# How can I add a link to a image that I have added to my mobile nav with before selector ?

Tags: html, css

How can I add a link to a image that I have added to my mobile nav with before selector ?

This is the code I got so far:

```
 #navPanel:before {
    content:url('images/logo_ProCycling.png')  no-repeat;

    text-align: center;
    padding-left:10px;
    margin-top:20px;
    opacity:1;

}
```

Comment: You nedd to add link in #navPanel element

Answer (score 0):

Somthing like?

```
$('<a />',{'href':'https://blablabla.com', 'id':'linkId'}).appendTo('#navPanel');
$('#navPanel:before').appendTo('#linkId');
```